# Send a [[String:AnyObject]] using SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am requesting to an API using SwiftyJSON. I want to pass a value to a key which is in [[String: AnyObject]]:

```
var params = [String: AnyObject]()
parameters["paymentOptions"] = [["billingId": 1]]
```

So, directly passing it like this and making a request gave no response. So, I tried it like this:

```
var params = [String: AnyObject]()
parameters["paymentOptions"] = "\([["billingId": 1]])"
```

This gives an error from the API. I think I am doing something wrong here. How should I be sending the array?

This is how I make a request.

```
request(.POST, pathUrl, parameters: params)
```

Comment: which error you get